# Let $0<w<1$. Let $A=w^{1/k}$. Show that $\lim A =1$ as $k\to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know where to start on this problem. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about limits? How to calculate one?

Comment: Kind of yeah. Not the greatest at the analysis stuff

Comment: Suppose $w>1$. Use $x_n=\sqrt[n]w-1$ and the binomial theorem to show that $x_n$ goes to 0. Later use reciprocals for the case $0<w<1$

Comment: Couldn't I show that 1/x goes to 0 as x goes to infinity then just state that any base to the power of 0 is 1?

Answer (score 3):

I like to use logarithms with problems like this.

If $A = w^{1/k}$ then $\ln A = \frac{1}{k}\ln w$. Here, $w$ is a positive constant.

As $k \to \infty$ we have $\frac{1}{k} \to 0$ and so:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\ln A\right) = \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{k}\ln w\right) = \ln w \left(\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{k}\right) = \ln w \times 0 = 0$$

If $\ln A \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ then $A \to \mathrm{e}^0$ as $k \to \infty$. Hence $A \to 1$ as $k \to \infty$.

This is true for all $w > 0$, and hence for $0 < w < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** the base of the function(which is exponential) does not change as $k$ changes. Try looking at the graph of $f(x) = a^{\frac{1}{x}}$ and see what happens to $\frac{1}{x}$ as $x$ approaches infinity.

Comment: I know that as x gets very large, 1/x = 0 and anything to the power of 0 is 1. I just don't know how to show that with the proper wording

Comment: @Daniel Be careful saying that "anything to the power of 0 is 1". It is true that *for all non-zero* $x$, we have $x^0 = 1$. However $0^0$ is undefined.

Comment: OK. Is there anything else that I'd have to show to prove that?

Answer (score 0):

Since $0<w<1$ then $w^{1/n}=\frac{1}{1+g_n}$ for some $g_n>0$. By Bernoulli's inequality $$w=\frac{1}{(1+g_n)^n}\leq \frac{1}{(1+ng_n)}<\frac{1}{ng_n}$$
therefore $$0<g_n<1/nw$$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
$$0<1-w^{1/n}=\frac{g_n}{1+g_n}<g_n<1/nw$$
so $$|w^{1/n}-1|<\frac{1}{w}\frac{1}{n}$$
Now as $n\to \infty$ lim $w^{1/n}=1$

Comment: OK yeah that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: you welcome :). if you are satisfied then you can vote it up. :)

Comment: I would but I apparently need 15 reputation points to do that :/

Comment: no problem then. its ok. :)